# Get Status of Azure VM after Restart

Tags: powershell, azure

I am trying to get status of Azure VM after restart so that i can confirm whether it has restart successfully so that i am run couple of commands after that.

Below is the code I used to get status

```
(Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $DBServerName -Status).Statuses
```

It gave me below output everytime, even while restart.

```
Code          : ProvisioningState/succeeded
Level         : Info
DisplayStatus : Provisioning succeeded
Message       : 
Time          : 12/26/2016 12:34:49 PM

Code          : PowerState/running
Level         : Info
DisplayStatus : VM running
Message       : 
Time          :
```

What I need it something that will tell me that server is ready so that i can proceed with some other task.

Below is what i need to perform

1. Create VM
2. After VM comes up, install .net4.6.1 framework. This task will need server restart.
3. After server restart, proceed with installation of another component that is dependent on .NET4.6.1

Comment: did you gave some sleep time after you gave restart command for the status to update?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Mitul, if possible, you could stop your VM, then start your VM.

Comment: @Abhijithpk: I haven't gave any sleep time after restart command, as i was trying to get something that would be provided by Azure.

Comment: @Mitul: i have updated my question with details

Answer (score 0):

Based on my knowledge, I think you could check port 3389 to judge your VM whether is started.

You could use [Portqry](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17148) to check port. If you don't install it, you could install it, is is easy to install.

> ```
> ##The directory that PortQry installed. 
> cd "C:\PortQryUI" 
> do {
> $test = .\PortQry.exe -n shui.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com -e 3389
> if ($test -like 'Error opening socket: 10049')
> {
> Write-Host "Maybe the Windows is starting or closed."
> }
>
> Start-Sleep 30
>
>  }
> while($test -like 'Error opening socket: 10049')
>
> Write-Host "The Windows is started successful."
> ```

According to your description, I test in my lab. It works for me.
[image]